# New garage door trips breaker

Tags: doors, garage

We have a 3 car garage. We had 3 new garage openers installed. Genie Machforce. They are on their own 20 amp breaker.  They periodically keep tripping breaker usually when you double hit the button or hit two openers at same time. The old ones worked fine just the motors were going bad. We have called genie but they have no solutions. They did trip breaker during programming as well. Which goes with hitting button twice. We have tried unplugging one but the others  still trips breaker if button is hit twice before letting first action complete cycle. Just need to know where to start looking whether programming error or electrical.  Also read about GFI compatibility issue but genie could not answer any questions about that so I’m not sure how to check it. Thanks for any help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are these on a GFI breaker?

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it? Also, how many amps or HP are these openers?

Comment: Well, Genie doesn't have an option there.  GFCI is now mandatory in garages, so a garage door opener that trips GFCIs is about as useful as a kitchen sink that is damaged by water.

Comment: Thank you. They are on a gfi breaker which is 20 amp. The garage openings are 2.5 amps. What we have figured out is the garage door openers are not compatible with the current gfi breaker.. so we have an electrician scheduled to change out the breaker to one that is compatible if we can figure out what it requires. All garage doors work fine and at same time when not on the garage gfi circuit.